# Symfony 2 KnpSnappy Bundle Error

Tags: php, symfony, wkhtmltopdf

I m trying to implement Knp SNappy Bundle to display an html page as a pdf from my controller.
I'm stuck with this error :

```
The exit status code '1' says something went wrong:
stderr: "Loading pages (1/6)
[> ] 0%
[======> ] 10%
[==========> ] 18%
Warning: Failed to load file:///slick/slick.css (ignore)
Warning: Failed to load file:///slick/slick-theme.css (ignore)
Warning: Failed to load file:///clovis-app/style.css (ignore)
Warning: Failed to load file:///clovis-app/estimate.css (ignore)
Warning: Failed to load file:///clovis-app/res/clovis.png (ignore)
Warning: Failed to load file:///js/collection.js (ignore)
Warning: Failed to load file:///clovis-app/script.js (ignore)
Warning: Failed to load file:///clovis-app/estimate.js (ignore)
[============================================================] 100%
Counting pages (2/6)
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1
Resolving links (4/6)
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1
Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
[> ] Preparing
[===================> ] Page 1 of 3
[=======================================> ] Page 2 of 3
[============================================================] Page 3 of 3
Done
Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentOperationNotPermittedError"    
stdout: ""

command: "C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe" --lowquality "C:\Users\Razgort\AppData\Local\Temp\knp_snappy55ae6cc4ad0353.17775155.html" "C:\Users\Razgort\AppData\Local\Temp\knp_snappy55ae6cc4ad41d0.64896673.pdf".
```

Here is my configuration file :

```
knp_snappy:
pdf:
    enabled:    true
    binary:     "\"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe\""
    options:    []
image:
    enabled:    true
    binary:     "\"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltoimage.exe\""
    options:    []
```

and here is how i render the view :

```
        $html =  $this->renderView('CompanyBundle:Estimate:edit.html.twig', array(
        'estimate' => $estimate,
        'estimateForm'   => $estimateForm->createView(),
        'articleForm' => $articleForm->createView(),
        'articleSelectForm' => $articleSelectForm->createView(),
        'manpowerForm' => $manpowerForm->createView(),
        'manpowerSelectForm' => $manpowerSelectForm->createView(),
        'workSelectForm' => $workSelectForm->createView(),
        'workForm' => $workForm->createView(),
        'bundleForm' => $bundleForm->createView(),
        'bundleSelectForm' => $bundleSelectForm->createView(),
    ));
    return new Response(
        $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html),
        200,
        array(
            'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="file.pdf"'
        )
    );
```

I eard there is problems on MAMP, i use wamp, didn't see any issue with it.
I'll really appreciate some help on this =)

Edit :

I modified some things in order to generate a pdf first. And i did. But the pdf only contents my login page. Then i added the access to my session and it worked. But when i try to send it as a response like that :

```
        $session = $this->get('session');
    $session->save();
    session_write_close();

    $pageUrl = $this->generateUrl('estimate_preview', array('id' => $id), true);
    return new Response(
        $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutput($pageUrl, array('cookie' => array($session->getName() => $session->getId()))),
        200,
        array(
            'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="file.pdf"'
        )
    );
```

it doesn't seem to work either... Does someone have an idea why ?

Answer (score 1):

Try by using forward (getContent()) method instead render.

```
$html =  $this->forward('CompanyBundle:Estimate:edit.html.twig', array(
        'estimate' => $estimate,
        'estimateForm'   => $estimateForm->createView(),
        'articleForm' => $articleForm->createView(),
        'articleSelectForm' => $articleSelectForm->createView(),
        'manpowerForm' => $manpowerForm->createView(),
        'manpowerSelectForm' => $manpowerSelectForm->createView(),
        'workSelectForm' => $workSelectForm->createView(),
        'workForm' => $workForm->createView(),
        'bundleForm' => $bundleForm->createView(),
        'bundleSelectForm' => $bundleSelectForm->createView(),
    ))->getContent();

$pdf =$this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html);
```

First check by printing $pdf and then you can return it as a response.

Comment: Hu, ty for your answer. I just tested that but it dooesnt' seem to work : When i do it , i just get a blank page and after a time it shoes maximum time reacher of something like that and then an other blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Do this for all your CSS files in your Twig:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ app.request.scheme ~'://'~ app.request.httpHost ~ asset('css/my_custom_stylesheet.css') }}" />
```

The  CSS folder must be directly under /web

Answer (score 0):

Knp SNappy Bundle is a wrapper. In your symphony side you do all right.

But in your HTML-to-render you have relative URLs, that is not absolute to HTTP-server. So when wkhtmltopdf see in your HTML url like '/dsasdaasd/sdaasd.wtf', it does not know, that it's your site.

1st option. Render PDF by URL (pass some option like "use print styles").
2nd: Use in your HTML absolute pathes to assets.

Anyway there is no absolute correct HTML, so you can meet in the future more errors like this -- even if in huge HTML there will be only one not-found-image. So try to find some options in snappy to ignore these errors as in the result pdf will be generated ok.

Answer (score 0):

in Symfony version 4.4 `getOutput()` works fine ...

```
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
   use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;

    private $session;
    private $pdf;
    
    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session, Pdf $pdf)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->pdf = $pdf;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/estimate/preview/pdf/{id}", name="estimate_preview_pdf")
     */ 
        
     public function estimate_preview_pdf($id): Response
     {
            $this->session->save();
            $pageUrl = $this->generateUrl('estimate_preview_html', array('id' => $id), false);
            return new Response(
                $this->pdf->getOutput($pageUrl,array('cookie' => array($this->session->getName() => $this->session->getId()))),
                200,
                array(
                    'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
                    'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="file.pdf"'
                )
            );
      }
```

Code `$this->session->save()` is important... without it it gets stuck